# Visual Studio can not preview project in browser

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

For some reason I have one project I can not preview in a browser. It seems it can open the others fine. In Google Chrome it says `"Server error"` and `IE` reports `Page can not be displayed`. Nothing changed. Any ideas?

Comment: What properties have been set for the project?  Right-click the project, go to properties, go to 'Web' and see the 'Servers' section.  Are you using the 'Visual Studio Development Server' option, or IIS/Custom?

Comment: Also, what version of Studio are you using, and what kind of project is it?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a result of no start up project being selected. Simply going to Solution > Properties > then selecting a start up project fixed the issue.

Or going to Solution > Properties > RightClick file> Select Brows with > choose your default browser  .